# Why isn't memcpy guaranteed to be safe for non-POD types?

Tags: c++

I read about this paragraph from a few questions posted on SO.

I can't quite figure out why `memcpy` isn't guaranteed to be safe for a non-POD type. My understanding is that `memcpy` is just a bit-wise copy.

Below is a quote from standard

> For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of `POD` type `T`, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type `T`,
>   the underlying bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into an array of `char` or `unsigned char`.41) If the content
>   of the array of `char` or `unsigned char` is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original
>   value.
>
> ```
> # define N sizeof (T)
> char buf[N];
> T obj ; // obj initialized to its original value
> std :: memcpy (buf , & obj , N); // between these two calls to std::memcpy,
>                                  // obj might be modified
> std :: memcpy (& obj , buf , N); // at this point, each subobject of obj of 
>                                  // scalar type holds its original value
> ```

Comment: What happens if there's a copy constructor defined that does something other than a bitwise copy?

Comment: `memcpy` is a bitwise copy. Non-POD types do no not necessarily exhibit bitwise copy semantics.

Comment: but that is not what the standard says... the standard says that ..."the object shall subsequently hold its original value", which is true when memcpy the non-POD types.

Comment: @LeonLi it's not. The original value is not the original bytes.

Comment: @R.M.F I am still confused...why "original value" cannot be preserved after two memcpy's. What could have been changed during the memcpy, if  the memcpy is just a bitwise operation.

Comment: @LeonLi memcpy only copies the bytes. The value can be more than the bytes. Here's an example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ed6efeb43bbaab52a7e38d0de7b0e2ea-e8512a4c58cb45810e5b7028e6b90c7d

Comment: The lesson to take from this is that C++ is a high-level language with low-level escape hatches, not a low-level language. Stop thinking in terms of bits and bytes and start thinking in terms of values and objects and numbers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes You don't need a shared_ptr for that. You don't even need memcpy. You can take *any* pointer to an object, store its value, end the pointed-to-object life and restore the original value, bingo. UB. I doubt that the OP meant that. In a sense both the shared_ptr (or *any* pointer) still have their "original value" after restoring it bit-wise; it's just that the memory at that address happens to have been invalidated. One could, of course, do that by other means as well (e.g. by freeing the pointee manually), without any memcpy. That is not really related to the memcpy.

Comment: So the question is whether there is a way that memcpying back and forth *eo ipso* can invalidate an object (or is UB a such). That is how I understand the standard there.

Answer (score 17):

Try bit-wise copying `std::shared_ptr<>`. You might find that your program blows up in your face more often than not.

You'll encounter this problem with any class whose copy constructor does something other than a bit-wise copy. In the case of `std::shared_ptr<>`, it'll copy the pointer but won't increment the reference count, so you'll end up freeing the shared object and its reference count early, and then blowing up when the copied `shared_ptr` tries to decrement the freed reference count.

---

*UPDATE:* It was pointed out that this doesn't quite answer the question, which is fair, since I mainly addressed the idea of copying shared_ptr to shared_ptr, not shared_ptr to char[] and back again. However, the principle still holds.

If you bit-wise copy a shared_ptr to a char[], assign a different value to the shared_ptr, then copy the char[] back over, the end result may be to leak one object and double-delete another, i.e., UB.

The same might happen with a POD, but that would be a bug in the program logic. Bit-wise copying back into the POD equivalent of a modified shared_ptr would be perfectly valid as long as the program understands and accommodates such an event. Doing so for a std::shared_ptr generally won't work.

Comment: This, I think, does not answer the question. I'm confident that after copying the bytes of a shared_ptr to a char array and (immediately) back, the shared_ptr will have its original value. The OP does not want to do anything with the copy but copy it back and wonders why these back-and-forth equivalence semantics are only defined for PODs. (I can imagine that a garbage collection scheme might change the pointer values of the original thus invalidating the pointer values in the copy, but aside from MT issues which could also arise with PODs, I think, I cannot imagine what could go wrong.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I see your point, but the answer still holds. I've updated it for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine a class that holds some pointer to a buffer like this:

```
class Abc {
    public:
    int* data;
    size_t n;
    Abc(size_t n)
    {
        this->n = n;
        data = new int[n];
    }

    // copy constructor:
    Abc(const Abc& copy_from_me)
    {
        n = copy_from_me.n;
        data = new int[n];
        memcpy(data, copy_from_me.data, n*sizeof(int));
    }
    Abc& operator=(const Abc& copy_from_me)
    {
        n = copy_from_me.n;
        data = new int[n];
        memcpy(data, copy_from_me.data, n*sizeof(int));
        return *this;
    }

    ~Abc()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
} ;
```

If you just memcopy one of its constructed instance, you'll get two instances pointing onto the same buffer `data`, because they will have the same address of buffer in `data` pointer. If you modify the data in one instance, it will be modified in the other too.

This means you didn't truly cloned it into two independent classes. Moreover, if you then delete both classes, the buffer would be freed twice from the memory which would crash.
So the class has to have a copy constructor defined and you have to rather copy it using the constructor.

Comment: This actually proves nothing. The same would happen with struct containing a pointer, and struct is a POD type.

Comment: @Dariusz In C++ `struct` is just like `class`, the only difference is that `struct` defaults to `public` and `class` to `private`.

Comment: @Dariusz: just because something is a struct, doesn't make it a POD. I think the point that the post is trying to make is the same as in the rule of three: the dtor could try to delete the memory pointed to by data, which when memcpyd would lead to a double delete, which the copy ctor solves by doing a deep copy.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I think I know what you both mean, but the answer does not explain that, at least not in the form it was when I first commented. The code shown at the moment does not show the problem either. I think the answer has to be expanded to be good.

Comment: This new example is not much better. It will break whether you memcpy or whether you do a regular copy like `Abc y = x;`. It's not memcpying it that is broken, it's the class itself. Of course broken code is broken.

Comment: Is it better now? I have added a copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

In general the problem is that **objects introduce not only data, but also behaviors**.

By copying the data manually we may break the inherent behavior of the object, which may rely on the copy constructor.

A great example would be any *shared* or *unique pointer* - by copying it we break the "deal" we made with that class when we used it.

Regardless of the copying process being semantically correct or not, the idea behind doing that is wrong and violates the object programming paradigm.

Sample code:

```
/** a simple object wrapper around a pthread_mutex
 */
class PThreadMutex
{
   public:
    /** locks the mutex. Will block if mutex is already locked */
    void lock();

    /** unlocks the mutex. undefined behavior if mutex is unlocked */
    void unlock();

   private:
    pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;

};

/** a simple implementation of scoped mutex lock. Acquires and locks a Mutex on creation,
 * unlocks on destruction
 */
class ScopedLock
{
  public:
    /** constructor specifying the mutex object pointer to lock
     * Locks immediately or blocks until lock is free and then locks
     * @param mutex the mutex pointer to lock
     */
    ScopedLock ( PThreadMutex* mutex );

    /** default destructor. Unlocks the mutex */
    ~ScopedLock ();

    /** locks the mutex. Will block if mutex is already locked */
    void unlock();


  private:

    PThreadMutex* m_mutex;

    // flag to determine whether the mutex is locked
    bool m_locked;

    // private copy constructor - disable copying
    ScopedLock(ScopedLock &mutex) { (void)mutex; /* to get rid of warning */ };

};
```

If you copy `ScopedLock` class, manually unlock it, then restore the value and perform another unlock in constructor it will result in an undefined behavior (or at least EPERM error in the destructor).

Comment: Will it be broken in the example given? (no, it won't: there is only one T object there, so obviously its ID will be unique)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes indeed it won't, but I can't think of any that would. There are no operations explicitely made on that object and the only thing which will happen after that is the destructor call.

Comment: There's "between these two calls to std::memcpy, obj might be modified"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for example that you are writing a `String` class. Any instance of the class should hold a pointer to some dynamically allocated `char` array. If you memcopy such an instance, then the two pointers will be equal. Any modification of one string will affect the other one.

Comment: That won't be a problem in the example given, where an attempt to restore the original value of an object is made and not an attempt to make a second object with the same value. Note how the example has only one T object.

Comment: @r-martinho-fernandes that's not really true. since between the two memcpy calls the "obj might be modified", this includes that the string might be reallocate including freeing of no-longer-used memory. after the second mempcy, the original (now invalid) pointer will be restored and waiting for havoc.

Comment: @umläute Mention that in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

**C++11 note:** The quote in the question is a rather old version of the rule.  Since C++11, the requirement is *trivially copyable* which is much weaker than *POD*.

---

`memcpy` can be used from any object.  You get a bitwise image of the object.

If the object is not POD, then the image cannot be used as if it were the same type as the original object, because the lifetime rules require initialization to complete first.

In such cases, the image is merely a bunch of bytes.  That might still be useful, for example to detect changes in the internal representation of an object over time, but only operations valid on bytes (such as comparison between two images) are legal, and not operations that require an object of the original type.

Comment: Can you construct a concrete example where copying back-and forth to and from a char array invalidates an object or leads to UB? (Assuming single thread and no intervening code.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: You're naming a scenario which is substantially more restrictive.  Still, reading from and writing back to an object which is wholly or partially `const` yields undefined behavior, and might cause a hardware exception in real implementations.