# String copying error c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a number of strings and I have to check each char in the string if it corresponds to a specific group. If so, I want to remove that character.
I'm using this:

```
EDIT strcpy(input[0]+1, (input[0]+2));
```

by which I'm trying to skip the first character in the string and then remove the next one.
For example, I have "Jones", I skip "J", remove "o" and want to have "Jnes" left.

Does anyone know why the above doesn't work or of there's a simpler solution to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't count on general purpose library functions to handle overlapping ranges unless they specifically state that they can do so.

Comment: This would be so much easier if you used `std::string`.

Comment: Dude, I'm not even sure you're calling ["strcpy_s()"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) correctly!!!  But "string copying ... C++" really means you should use std::string, if at all possible.  IMHO...

Comment: Did you mean to write `strcpy(&input[0]+1, &input[0]+2)`, or maybe `strcpy(input+1, input+2)`? The way you wrote it should have caused compiler warnings about type mismatches, and it shouldn't have copied anything at all.

Comment: This should be tagged C, not C++ imo. strcpy is only in C++ for backwards-compatibility with C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html):

> The strings may not overlap

The only array copying function that's required to handle overlapping source and destination is `memmove()`. This requires you to specify the number of bytes to copy, so you'll have to use `strlen()` to calculate this.

```
memmove(input+1, input+2, strlen(input+2)+1); // +1 for the null byte
```

Comment: +1 for `memmove`, it's the way to go for overlapping source and destination within a string. Warning though, this is only true if the moved objects are "simple" enough (eg, `char`s); moving objects that contain self-referring pointers for instance will most likely cause segfaults. Use `std::copy` instead for complex types.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn As long as the source and destinations are properly aligned for the pointers, I don't see why `memmove` would have a problem. Obviously you're not going to be moving overlapping source and destination if they're not on even boundaries of the structure containing the pointers.

Comment: @Barmar I was once given this example as a case of failure: `struct X { char small[4]; char* buffer; X() : buffer(small) {} };`. Move and `buffer` won't point to the right address anymore (of course, no one would do this exactly, but this illustrates the point).

Comment: I think what you're pointing out is that it only works for POD structures.

Comment: I don't know if this is too restrictive. I think as long as nothing moved depends on something that's being moved (eg, member pointer pointing to a member, or to another moved object) it should be fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810174/why-isnt-memcpy-guaranteed-to-be-safe-for-non-pod-types

Comment: Obviously if there are other pointers into this object, they won't work properly if you move what they point to.  It doesn't really matter how you move them.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy_s` takes three arguments not two:

```
errno_t strcpy_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource 
);
```

**It is a non-std function**. Instead use either :

`strcpy` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/   or
`strncpy` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/

Comment: Sorry, I meant strcpy(input[0]+1, (input[0]+2); Neither would let me put input[0]+1 as a first argument. I want to skip the first letter and remove the second one

Comment: Because it expects char* and you are passing a `char`. `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );`

Comment: So how can I achieve what I want? :)