# resize dynamically allocated memory C++ with ASSERT" _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) "

Tags: c++

Hi im writing some code that resize dynamically allocated memory.
here is some part of my code
initializing:

```
int size = 1;
string *rev = new string[size];
```

resizing part:

```
if (j >= size / 2){
    size = size * 2;
    string *temp = rev;
    rev = new string[size];
    memcpy(rev, temp, (size / 2)*sizeof(string));
    delete[] temp;            //  <- here causes the error!
}
```

when i comment out the "delete[] temp" my code works fine but with memory leaks.
So, how can i handle this error message "assert". please help!
thanks!

since someone pointed out that the assert is caused by other parts of my code.
here is the full version, which simply print the words out in reverse order in the given sentence.

```
void ReverseWords(string &sentence) {
char *str = new char[sentence.size()+1];

int size = 1;
string *rev = new string[size];
int j = 0;
int n = 0;
int m = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++){
    str[n] = sentence.at(i);
    n++;
    if (str[n-1] == ' '){
        str[n-1] = '\0';
        if (j >= size / 2){
            size = size * 2;
            string *temp = rev;
            rev = new string[size];
            memcpy(rev, temp, (size / 2)*sizeof(string));
            delete[] temp; 
        }
        rev[j] = str;
        cout << rev[j] << endl;
        cout << j << endl;
        j++;
        memset(str, 0, sentence.size() + 1);
        n = 0;
    }
}
str[n] = '\0';
rev[j] = str;

int rev_size;
for( rev_size = 0; !rev[rev_size].empty(); rev_size++){
}
rev_size--;
while (rev_size >= 0){
    if (rev_size == 0){
        cout << rev[rev_size] << endl;
        break;
    }
    cout << rev[rev_size] << " ";
    rev_size--;
}

delete[] rev;
delete[] str;
return;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I fixed this error thanks for @πάντα ῥεῖ and @Retired Ninja. the error caused the assert was that i misused the memcpy function to non-pod type. I've changed the memcpy to:

```
            for (int m = 0; m < j; m++){
                rev[m].assign(temp[m]);
            }
```

and now everything is working! thanks guys.

Comment: Why are you using memcpy?  string is not a pod.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810174/why-isnt-memcpy-guaranteed-to-be-safe-for-non-pod-types

Comment: @Retired Ninja, OK thanks for point that out, i'll look into that later, but do you think thats the problem causing the assert?

Comment: @user3781833 _'but do you think thats the problem causing the assert?'_ That's very probable the reason, yes.

Comment: Here's one possible way it goes wrong out of many possibilities: Imagine you resize twice.  Since you copied the pointers in the strings and then destroyed the originals the memory they pointed to is freed.  The next time you resize the same memory is deleted again.

Comment: @Retired Ninja, I think you are right, when i run my code, the first iteration is ok, it happens when the second time. but i didnt get you quite clearly. can you explore more?

Answer (score 4):

The reason it is failing is that you are using `memcpy` to copy a `std::string`.  `std::string` is not a pod type and can't be bitwise copied safely, you must copy it in a way that uses the assignment operator or copy constructor.

A better solution would be to use a standard container like `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::deque<std::string>` to handle resizing and proper copying.

You could also greatly simplify your algorithm using `std::stringstream` to split up the words and store them in a container, but I assume this is for an assignment and don't want to completely rewrite your function, so I'll show you the minimum you need to do to fix the problem.

Instead of:

```
memcpy(rev, temp, (size / 2)*sizeof(std::string));
```

Use this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size / 2; ++i)
{
    rev[i] = temp[i];
}
```

Comment: thanks, i actually missed your post. but this is even better, i thought shallow copy will not work, so i used " rev[m].assign(temp[m]); " instead. But i was wrong

Comment: This is pretty much equivalent to using `assign`.  It's likely that `operator=()` calls `assign` internally.

Comment: +1 You are right, I have removed my answer because it was misleading