# STL Stack: read access violation

Tags: c++, stl

I have created a stack then using memcpy I copy the stack to a buffer. and later I try to create the stack object back using the buffer. But I am getting read access violation.

please see below the code that might explain the situation better.

```
Byte *targetdata;
class DATA
{
    std::stack<int> scatter;
}data;
...
...
memcpy(targetdata, &data, sizeof(DATA));
...
...
{
  DATA data2;
  memcpy(&data2, targetdata, sizeof(DATA));
}// Get a read access violation here.
```

Comment: `sizeof(DATA)` doesn't yield what you think.

Comment: C++ has Copy and Move Semantics, you shouldn't `memcopy` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `memcpy` with anything except POD ("plain old objects", i.e. structs which may contain other PODs or plain types like `int` only) because structures may be more complex than just a bunch of bytes. You may see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810174/why-isnt-memcpy-guaranteed-to-be-safe-for-non-pod-types) for details.

In your case, `stack<>` internally holds a pointer to a piece of memory (or even several pieces) which hold actual data. When `stack<>` is created, that piece of memory is allocated. When `stack<>` is destroyed (i.e. variable is not visible anymore, typically happens at `}`), that piece of memory is deallocated. If you try to access it afterwards, you get undefined behavior. If you (or somebody else) tries to destroy it afterwards, it's also undefined behavior called "double-free".

So, most probably you've got double-free or similar undefined behavior. Note that details heavily depend on the exact implementation of `stack<>`.

In C++ you should use `=` for assignments of complex structures:

```
stack<int> a;
// Fill up `a`.
stack<int> b;
b = a;
// Now `a` and `b` are independent stacks with same content.
```

That should also work with your structure without extra burden. With more complex structures, apply [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).